# Can a makefile pattern match contain both prefix and suffix as vairables?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to match a pattern in the rule to compile and generate binary files from c files like below

```
$(BIN_TARGETS) : $(BIN_DIR)/%.$(BIN_EXT) : $(BIN_DIR)/%.$(EXE_EXT)
```

I see the following error

```
../../rules/mkrules.mk:13: target 'bin/hello.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
```

I have tried the below and it seems to work

```
$(BIN_TARGETS) : $(BIN_DIR)/%.bin : $(BIN_DIR)/%.elf
```

I would like to make the file name extensions not fixed.

I have assigned the variables as shown below at the start of makefile

```
EXE_EXT = .elf
BIN_EXT = .bin
```

I see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) it is mentioned 
"Note that expansion using ‘%’ in pattern rules occurs after any variable or function expansions, which take place when the makefile is read."

So, aren't variables supposed to be expanded before % is substituted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

```
EXE_EXT = .elf
BIN_EXT = .bin

$(BIN_TARGETS) : $(BIN_DIR)/%.$(BIN_EXT) : $(BIN_DIR)/%.$(EXE_EXT)
```

So `$(BIN_DIR)/%.$(BIN_EXT)` expands to `$(BIN_DIR)/%..bin` (note double periods).

You'll have to decide whether you want the period either in the variable or in the pattern, but it can't be in both places.